# rails executing stored procedure error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a oracle stored procedure.

When I try to run the following in sql developer it works fine:

```
declare
   vPan varchar2(32);
   ErrorMsg varchar2(32);
   ErrorCode varchar2(32);
   SpErrorMsg varchar2(32);

begin


  DBO_MYDB.PKG_LTD.GET_PAN('8042049440330819','32', 'TEST', '0',vPan, ErrorMsg, ErrorCode, SpErrorMsg);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vPan);

end;
```

But when I try to run the above code in rails 3 as follows:

```
def number
    errormsg = nil
    errorcode = nil
    sperrormsg = nil
    vpan = nil

    sql =
  "BEGIN #{Pkgltd::PKG_LTD}.GET_PAN('
    8042049440330819','32', 'TEST', '0',vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg);
   END;"

   connection = self.connection.raw_connection
   cursor = connection.parse(sql)

     cursor.bind_param(:errormsg, nil, String, 1000)
     cursor.bind_param(:errorcode, nil, String, 1000)
     cursor.bind_param(:sperrormsg, nil, String, 1000
         cursor.bind_param(:vpan, nil, String, 1000)

   cursor.exec

   vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg, vpan = cursor[:vpan], cursor[:errormsg], cursor[:errorcode], cursor[:sperrormsg]
   cursor.close
   vpan
end
```

I get the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
>                            cursor.bind_param(:vpan, nil, String, 1000)

Any ideas?

I even tried:

```
cursor.bind_param(:vpan, nil, varchar2, 1000);
```

Not sure if the above is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is missing the closing `)`:

```
cursor.bind_param(:sperrormsg, nil, String, 1000
```

It should be:

```
cursor.bind_param(:sperrormsg, nil, String, 1000)
```